# Finding the date for 29th last month, two months ago, etc

Tags: php, date

I'm looking to find the date of the 29th of this month, the 29th of next month, the 29th of last month and so on...

I know you can use this kind of code to find days of the week:

```
$friday_last = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("last Friday"));
$friday_due = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("this Friday"));
```

Is there a similar way to find a certain day (29th) of each month or would I have to use a different code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `DateTime()` as it makes working with dates *much* easier. You'll notice I start by going to the first day of each month. That's so this doesn't break when you get to the 29th-30th of each month as weird date things start to happen.

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('first day of this month')->format("29/m/Y");
echo (new DateTime())->modify('first day of previous month')->format("29/m/Y");
echo (new DateTime())->modify('first day of next month')->format("29/m/Y");
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/564518)

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('first day of this month')->modify('-2 months')->format("29/m/Y");
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/564600)

Comment: I have tested it, and it seems to work find. The code shows up as red in my editor as if there is an issue, but it does seem to function. Any idea as to why?

Comment: What issue does your editor claim exists? It just might be that your editor doesn't understand the syntax.

Comment: I think you may be right with that, the editor is slightly out of date. Can this code go back any further? The maximum I need is the 29th of two months ago.

Comment: It can go as far back as you want. I'll update the answer to show two months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using `date()` with `strtotime()` will gives you 29th from each month within this year:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $d = "2016-" . $i . "-29";
        echo "29th of Month $i is: " . date("l", strtotime($d)) . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
29th of Month 1 is: Friday
29th of Month 2 is: Monday
29th of Month 3 is: Tuesday
29th of Month 4 is: Friday
29th of Month 5 is: Sunday
29th of Month 6 is: Wednesday
29th of Month 7 is: Friday
29th of Month 8 is: Monday
29th of Month 9 is: Thursday
29th of Month 10 is: Saturday
29th of Month 11 is: Tuesday
29th of Month 12 is: Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array with current and next 11 months 29th day (for **previous months** replace `+1 month` with `-1 month`. In this example I use `+1` to explain february issue, that is not present in past february):

```
$baseDate = date_create()->modify( 'first day of this month' );
$dates = array();
for( $i = 0; $i<12; $i++  )
{
    $newDate = clone $baseDate;
    $dates[] = $newDate->modify( '+28 days' );
    $baseDate->modify( '+1 month' );
}
```

The problem — as you can imagine — is with february:

```
foreach( $dates as $date )
{
    echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output:

```
2016-05-29
2016-06-29
2016-07-29
2016-08-29
2016-09-29
2016-10-29
2016-11-29
2016-12-29
2017-01-29
2017-03-01      <-----
2017-03-29
2017-04-29
```

If you want a result like “29th month's day OR last month's day” modify above `for` loop in this way:

```
for( $i = 0; $i<12; $i++  )
{
    $newDate = clone $baseDate;
    if( $newDate->modify( '+28 days' )->format( 'm' ) != $baseDate->format( 'm' ) )
    {
        $newDate->modify( 'last day of previous month' );
    }
    $dates[] = $newDate;
    $baseDate->modify( '+1 month' );
}
```

Result:

```
2016-05-29
2016-06-29
2016-07-29
2016-08-29
2016-09-29
2016-10-29
2016-11-29
2016-12-29
2017-01-29
2017-02-28      <-----
2017-03-29
2017-04-29
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this started, but now you can do so by using just `date()` and `strtotime()`, like this:

```
$d = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime('first day of 2 months ago'));
$l = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime('last day of 2 months ago'));

print_r($d); 
print_r($l);
```

Assuming today (2023-02-01) The above will display:

2022-12-01 00:00:00

2022-12-31 00:00:00

Sample:
https://onlinephp.io/c/db73f